# How can I apply physics to a curve game object in Phaser using Matter.js?

Tags: game-physics, phaser-framework, game-development, matter.js

I would like to apply physics to the following phaser game object using Matter.js:

```js
// Create curve
const startPoint = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(50, 260);
const controlPoint1 = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(610, 25);
const controlPoint2 = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(320, 370);
const endPoint = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(735, 550);
    
const bezierCurve = new Phaser.Curves.CubicBezier(startPoint, controlPoint1, controlPoint2, endPoint);
const curve = this.add.curve(1400, 1400, bezierCurve, 0xb5651d);
curve.setClosePath(true);
curve.setStrokeStyle(2, 0x654321);
```

Here is my physics initialization code:

```js
physics: {
  default: 'matter',
  matter: {
    gravity: {
      y: 0
    },
    debug: true
  }
},
```

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```js
  this.matter.add.gameObject(curve, {isStatic: true, shape: {
  type: 'fromVerts',
  verts: [bezierCurve.getPoints(100)],
  flagInternal: true,
  removeCollinear: 0,
  minimumArea: 0,
}});
```

That generates the following image:

[image]

With debug mode turned on you can see that the blue curve/edge describes the physical body object of the real rendered brown object. Ignore the profile picture image inside the green circle, that's just another physical game object.

I would like to have the offset of the physical body object adjusted so it matches the brown object (want them to 100% overlap).

I would like to avoid using the following Phaser matter.js factory methods:

```js
fromPhysicsEditor(x, y, config [, options] [, addToWorld])
fromSVG(x, y, xml [, scale] [, options] [, addToWorld])
```

Why? Because I want to randomly create these brown curved objects at runtime.

Can that be done? Or maybe I'm just using the api incorrectly. Can you even apply physics to such a complex phaser object (curve object)?